# Error creating django application: Pycharm MAC

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

I am trying to create a new django application on mac.  I have given all the permission for the respective folder.

I am getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: Do you have empty space in folder name after `/Uses/My`?

Comment: I am unable to locate the '/Users/My' dir.... there is a dir name 'My Mac'

Comment: It tries to create app somewhere inside that `My Mac` folder and due to empty space in that folder's name (space between `My` and `Mac`). You will need to change path for app or name of that folder.

Comment: Initially I have named my home dir as "My Mac", due to the space between the name, it was unable to process. Changing the name of home dir solved the problem THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Initially I have named my home dir as "My Mac", due to the space between the name, it was unable to process. changing the name of dir solved the problem THANK YOU